# Discord.js I'm having problems with the v13 bot reading the commands inside Commands/Moderation category folders

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having problems with the v13 bot reading the commands inside Commands/Moderation category folders

I just want the bot to recognize and turn on commands in category folders to be more organized

Commands/Moderation
Commands/Fun

my code:

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/Commands/*/*.js")
  .filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

/**
 * @type {Command[]}
*/
const commands = commandFiles.map(file => require(`../Commands/*/*/${file}`));

commands.forEach(cmd => {
    console.log(`Command ${cmd.name} loaded`);
    this.commands.set(cmd.name, cmd);
});

const slashCommands = commands
  .filter(cmd => ["BOTH", "SLASH"].includes(cmd.type))
  .map(cmd => ({
      name: cmd.name.toLowerCase(),
      description: cmd.description,
      permissions: [],
      options: cmd.slashCommandOptions,
      defaultPermission: true
}));
```

Error:

```
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './src/Commands/*/*.js'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at Client.start (C:\Users\stifler\Desktop\botv13\src\Structures\Client.js:31:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stifler\Desktop\botv13\src\index.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './src/Commands/*/*.js'
}
```

Comment: Did you actually replace the `*`s?

Comment: @MrMythical  I did not understand your question

Comment: In your folder names?

Comment: @MrMythical My folder names are normal.

Commands/Fun
Commands/Economy

inside each folder are the corresponding commands, but the error bot doesn't work

Comment: Remove the `*`'s from the path and replace them with your real directory names. Or did you just "censor" the paths for this question?

Comment: @MrMythical In case this is for him to find the commands inside the folder regardless of the folder name is defined or not he will find the commands inside the directory

Comment: fs does not support wildcards in paths. You would need an external library for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the bot read command file inside the Subfolder of Commands folder, here's how i do it

```js
client.commands = new Collection(); // Discord.Collection();
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands'); // Name this as yours Command Folder name

for (const folder of commandFolders) // this loop will retrieve all subfolders
{
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')); // Retrieve the cmd files inside subfolders
  
    for (const file of commandFiles) // this loop will retrieve all command files
    {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command) // i use client. idk if you using bot or this.
        console.log(`${command.name} is loaded`)
    }
}
```